# Open new APN setting page through Android app Programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, apn

Since "android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" is restricted by Google, though I am not be able to modify the apn value programmatically.

Please refer below image
[image: In this image we have APN setting, I just want to open third part of this image which is populated by my values using code, though user only need to save these value by pressing save button.]

In this image we have APN setting, I just want to open third part of this image which is populated by my values using code, though user only need to save these value by pressing save button.

Is it possible to do that, Opening the 'Edit access point ' page along with my values.

Or any other alternative to modify or add new APN setting through coding.

Comment: Did you mean 'Is it possible to do that'?

Comment: ya ..m sorry for my mistake